# OpenCL counter variable

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencl

I'm performing **Otsu's method** (link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) in order to determine how many black pixels are in the raw frame. I'm trying to optimize process and I want to do it with **OpenCL**. Is there any way to pass the **single variable** to OpenCL kernel and increment it, instead of passing the **whole buffer** when it's not necessary?

Comment: Can you post some pseudo-code of what you would *like* to do? I don't understand the question. (What single variable?)

Comment: using Otsu for counting black pixels doesn't make any sense which kind of makes your question obsolete.

Comment: Aren't parameters themselves constant? IIRC, only the pointed memory by them can be changable. Didn't you try 1-element array?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you want to solve is very much like a global reduction. While you could use a single output variable and atomic read/modify/write access, it would be very slow (due to contention on the atomic) unless the thing you are counting is very sparse (not the case here). So you should use the same techniques used for reduction, which is to do partial sums in parallel, and then merge those together. Google for "OpenCL reduction" and you'll find some great examples, such as this one: https://developer.amd.com/resources/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/